# NVidia driver update in Windows 7 issues

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm writing this from a Ubuntu CD installation, because I upgraded my video card drivers and now I can't boot anymore in Widows...

My video card is GeForce 8600M GT, and the drivers to which I updated are [270.61](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/notebook-win7-winvista-270.61-whql-driver-uk.html) (from 260). After I installed them I didn't restart normally because the installation program didn't ask... A little later my computer hanged (for some other reason) so I had to force shut down by holding the power button pressed.

Then after I power it up again, just before the Windows welcome screen the computer freezes and I see random characters on the screen and start hearing some high pitched sounds which I think is the hard drive working more than usual (it's a SSD).

I tried safe mode but the same happens after the loading drivers message...

So how can I delete/disable the nvidia drivers in my Windows installation from Ubuntu?
I don't want to re-install Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. **Try booting into Safe Mode and uninstall the Driver**.
Press F8 and select SafeMode with Networking. Try this [post](http://www.ehow.com/how_6761637_uninstall-ati-drivers-safe-mode.html).
It will only load essential drivers (and that does not include any type of display drivers)
(PS: I see you said SafeMode did not work but added this just for completeness. You can always try once more :) )

B. If you have the original Windows 7 DVD, you can **try repairing your Windows Installation**.

C. In case you don't have the original DVD, you can create a **System Repair Disc** from another Windows 7 machine, boot your machine from it and repair the installation.

Comment: I used the Windows installation disk, clicked on `repair your computer` and it worked! I think it was a hard disk problem because during the "computer repairing" it said it was fixing hard disk errors... Tx!